# What is the use of "useMaster: true" in sequelize(nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

So I was going through a project codebase(nodejs 10) and they are using sequelize for executing queries in Mysql and at some places they are using `useMaster: true`.

I am just wondering what is it there for? Anyone having any idea?

Example code:

```
[error , coupons ] = await to(@wagner.get('sequelize').query( query , { useMaster: true, replacements : [coupon_offset,parseInt(limit)] ,type: @wagner.get('sequelize').QueryTypes.SELECT } ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Didi you check the official documentation?
It says about `useMaster` in the `Params` section of `query` instance method:

```
Force the query to use the write pool, regardless of the query type.
```

See [query method](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-method-query)
I'm not sure if it's applicable to MySQL but still I'd recommend to find out more about write pools.